# How to adapt an integrated graphics card as if it were dedicated to another PC

Tags: graphics-cards, pc, pcie, video-adapters

I have a tower PC, the power supply stopped working so I am recovering functional parts, like my hard drive, RAM and I also want to recover my video card, I can buy a PCI express adapter to be able to use the integrated video card from my old PC as a dedicated video card from my other tower PC. Since both have PCI express ports. Any recommendation.
I hope to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible except on a multi-cpu board. Since the integrated GPU lives inside the CPU it is impossible to put it on a PCIe card. Only dedicated GPUs are reusable across different CPUs